# dataset highlight rows based on cell values

Tags: dataset

With the new `Dataset/Background` option feature introduced in 12.1, I would like to highlight the rows when either of the two columns has one of the target values in its cell.
For example, I have the following data:

```
data = Transpose@Dataset@AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 10}]]
```

Iwould like to highlight those rows in red when either col `a` or `b` equals `1` or `10`.

[image]

I can highlight rows based on one-col value, but don't know how to add the 2nd col to the expression.

```
Dataset[data, Background -> (Switch[#3[#2[[1]], "a"], 1 | 10, LightRed, _, White] &)]
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[77];
data = Transpose@Dataset@AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, 
          RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 10}]];
     
Dataset[data, 
 Background -> Normal[MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> 
      If[Or @@ (MatchQ[1 | 10] /@ {#a, #b}), Pink, White] &, data, {1}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of MapIndexed. I think you meant to write `{#a, #b}` instead instead of `{#a, #c}`

Comment: Thank you @theorist. I had misread the question. Updated with the correction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really like the way of using MapIndexed and Or.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = Transpose@
  Dataset@AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, 
    RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 10}]]

rowcolors = 
 If[MemberQ[{1, 10}, #[[1]]] || MemberQ[{1, 10}, #[[2]]], LightRed, White] & /@ Normal[data];

Dataset[data, Background -> {rowcolors}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
rowcolors = 
 Table[If[MemberQ[{1, 10}, data[n, "a"]] || 
    MemberQ[{1, 10}, data[n, "b"]], LightRed, White], {n, Length[data]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wonder would it be possible to implement via the Pattern Matching? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
SeedRandom[3]
data =
  RandomInteger[{1,10},{10, 3}] //
  Query[Dataset, AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, #]&]
```

and a helper function:

```
color = Replace @ {KeyValuePattern["a"|"b" -> 1|10] -> LightRed, _ -> White};
```

then we could write:

```
Dataset[data, Background -> Normal@data[{All}, color]]
```

or

```
Dataset[data, Background -> (color[Normal@#3[#2[[1]]]]&)]
```

[image: dataset with coloured rows]

Comment: This is also very nice solution. I have never learned `KeyValuePattern` before your answer. Thanks!